# Possible to access redux store when user not in current component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Imagine I have two components, `LoginComponent` and `MainScreenComponent`.

I have created an eventListener at `LoginComponent`, which to receive push notifications anytime. Upon user login, we will navigate user to `MainScreenComponent`, so `LoginComponent` no longer active.

```
class LoginComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
  super(props);

  OneSignal.init('xx');
  OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
  this.context = context;
 }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
  OneSignal.removeEventListener('registered', this.onRegistered);
  OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
  OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
}

onOpened(openResult) {

  const { dispatch } = this.context.store; //Cannot read property store from undefined?
  const boundActions = bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
  // this.props.storeNotification({ notification: openResult.notification });
}
```

Since my event Listener stays in `LoginComponent`, I would have to access the action in order to store the notification received to store but apparently `this.context` is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

> I have created an eventListener at LoginComponent

### Separation of concerns.

Extract the push notification listener/handler from your `Login` component.

I would make a dedicated component, sibling of `XXXScreens` components (LoginScree, MainScreen, etc.) like so:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <>   // a shorthand syntax for Fragment
    <PushNotificationsListener></PushNotificationsListener>
    <XXXScreen></XXXScreen>
  </>
</Provider>
```

Hence, your push notification listener will always remain active even when navigating between screens.

By the way, don't hesitate to make use of [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) along with your [containers](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0); it simplifies and optimizes a lot the redux handling around React components.